# Can you recommend a good GUI (X, Java, web-based, or curses-like console) for syslog and other Linux logs?

Tags: linux, log-files, syslog, logging

I am looking for a convenient tool to view and manage my Linux (Debian, postfix, dovecot, iptables, etc) server logs. Would you, please, share your choice and experience?

Comment: Do you want to lock at logs of a specific server or aggregate the logs of many servers?  Have you looked at [splunk](http://serverfault.com/search?q=splunk).

Answer (score 3):

[Splunk!](http://www.splunk.com)  Surely there's an ad somewhere on this very page :)

> [Download Splunk for free](http://www.splunk.com/download). You'll get
>   all of the Enterprise features of
>   Splunk for 60 days and you can index
>   up to 500 megabytes of data per day.
>   After 60 days, or anytime before then,
>   you can convert to a perpetual Free
>   license or purchase an Enterprise
>   license to continue using the expanded
>   functionality designed for multi-user
>   Enterprise deployments.

Answer (score 2):

I up-voted Zerodache's recommendation for Splunk.  Great GUI and it will just eat your logs and allow you to easily mine through them.  If your daily volume is low (I think < 500MB) then it is free.

For interactive watching of different log files give MultiTail a try (http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/).

-ab

Answer (score 1):

[LogAnalyzer](http://loganalyzer.adiscon.com/) might be worth a look.  It used be called phpLogCon and was originally developed by the same person as [Rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[KSystemLog](http://ksystemlog.forum-software.org/) is a KDE application that works pretty well as a log viewer. It's designed for home use, i.e. viewing the logs on a single system with an easily manageable GUI, so if you have a more complex setup, it probably would be inadequate.